# Append prevent duplicate jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have this code

```
var values = ["15", "30"];
var select = $('<select class="form-control">').prop('id', 'fcorte').prop('name', 'fcorte');
$(values).each(function(e) {
    select.append($("<option>")
        .prop('value', this)
        .text(this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1))
        );
});
var label = $("<label class='col-form-label'>").prop('for', 'fcorte').text("Choose your pets: ");
var br = $("<br>");
$(".fcorte").append(label).append(br).append(select);
```

But when I go back in I have a duplicate.
The form is done by ajax without page refresh

Some help...? and thanks in advance

Comment: The code you've shown in the question cannot create duplicates, it's only invoked once. I'm guessing it's part of a larger block of code which has been omitted, which I would assume is being called in a loop or under an event handler that's called repeatedly?

Comment: I edited the correct code
This code make a dynamic jquery dropdown

Comment: could you please clarify this, when you say «when I go back in I have a duplicate», what you mean exactly "go back in", hitting the browser's back button?

Comment: *The form is done by ajax without page refresh* - sounds like you need to remove the #fcorte from .fcorte before adding it again.